# Install Module in Magento 2.2.x without using CLI

Tags: magento2, upgrade, cli

I tried the system() ex.( system(php bin/magento setup:upgrade) ) function of PHP to execute the CLI command of Magento, but no luck. 
Is there any other way? It is very hassle to use **Flush Static Files Cache** in Admin Panel just to apply the CSS or JS I added. We are using shared server, that means there is no SSH Account provided to us.

Answer (score 0):

Login through SSH to your server (using something like PUTTY)

Use the command

cd path/to/magento/install/

Obviously change the path above to your actual Magento install, maybe

cd public_html/magento/

From there to install a module

php bin/magento setup:upgrade

php bin/magento setup:di:compile

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

NOTE: FTP into your server and check in public_html/magento/bin/ that the magento file has the permission to be executed i.e. 0744

Comment: We have no SSH account, since we are only using shared server. Is there other way to run the CLI commands through file and execute it browser?

Comment: You would need to use the object manager class in a module as per below.  I would STRONGLY suggest you ask your hosting provider to give you some kind of shell access

Comment: I asked that before to the hosting provider, but they dont give us shell access/ssh account.

Answer (score 0):

Try this
`
getObjectManager();

```
$modules = array('VENDORNAME_MODULENAME');
try{
    /* Code to enable a module [ php bin/magento module:enable VENDORNAME_MODULENAME ] */
    $moduleStatus = $objectManager->create('Magento\Framework\Module\Status')->setIsEnabled(true,$modules);


    /* Code to run setup upgrade [ php bin/magento setup:upgrade ] */
    $installerFactory = $objectManager->create('Magento\Setup\Test\Unit\Console\Command\UpgradeCommandTest')->testExecute();


    /* Code to clean cache [ php bin/magento:cache:clean ] */
    try{
        $_cacheTypeList = $objectManager->create('Magento\Framework\App\Cache\TypeListInterface');
        $_cacheFrontendPool = $objectManager->create('Magento\Framework\App\Cache\Frontend\Pool');
        $types = array('config','layout','block_html','collections','reflection','db_ddl','eav','config_integration','config_integration_api','full_page','translate','config_webservice');
        foreach ($types as $type) {
            $_cacheTypeList->cleanType($type);
        }
        foreach ($_cacheFrontendPool as $cacheFrontend) {
            $cacheFrontend->getBackend()->clean();
        }
    }catch(Exception $e){
        echo $msg = 'Error during cache clean: '.$e->getMessage();die();
    }   
}catch(Exception $e){
    echo $msg = 'Error during module enabling : '.$e->getMessage();die();
}`
```

Comment: Where to upload and run this codes? @Rahul.

Comment: create your simple plugin and add controller

Comment: Then how to run this codes after creating a plugin?

Comment: opps sorry your module already not enable ..

Comment: work with exciting enabled module

Comment: getObjectManager(); is included in the code?

Comment: yes , sorry but its stackexchange issue.

Answer (score 0):

Add your module name in app/etc/config.php like as

> 'Vendor_Module'=>1

Then run below code from root like as create file **custom.php** in root

Then run url like as below

> http://your domain url/custom.php

```
<?php

use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;

require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';

$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);

$obj = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();

$state = $obj->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');
$k[0]='bin/magento';
$k[1]='setup:upgrade'; // write your proper command like setup:upgrade,cache:enable etc...
$_SERVER['argv']=$k;
try {
    $handler = new \Magento\Framework\App\ErrorHandler();
    set_error_handler([$handler, 'handler']);
    $application = new Magento\Framework\Console\Cli('Magento CLI');
    $application->run();
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    while ($e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
        echo $e->getTraceAsString();
        echo "\n\n";
        $e = $e->getPrevious();
    }
}
```

Comment: So the code above will also be named 'Vendor_Module.php' ?

Comment: see my post i have write file name and way of code run

Comment: what is your module name check in regisration.php file inside module

Comment: \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Vendor_Module',
    __DIR__
);      this is the code inside registration.php

Comment: After I run this codes it returns blank. No notification/message.

Comment: ok then add Vendor_Module in app/etc/config.php

Comment: yes it will not give you any message but it has added your module in magento

Comment: Yes I already added it. Does it execute all the cli commands of magento?

Comment: yes you need to just change that line of code with new command which you want to use $k[1]='setup:upgrade'; like as $k[1]='setup:static-content:deploy en_US en_GB" etc

Comment: Only registration.php will be inside in app/code/Vendor/Module/ ? It that right?